# ip adress of a server at runtime

Tags: c

I developed a client task in C and a server task in C. The client needs the server IP address to connect to the server. The problem is: I don't know in advance which machine will run the client and which machine will run the server so I can know the ip address of the server only at runtime
My question: how at run time the client will know the ip address of the server?

Comment: why don't you use a dns entry instead? That can configured to any ip address?

Comment: [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)?

Comment: Can you explain your idea further ? thank you so much for help

Comment: what kind of network are you talking about? you need to be more specific.

Comment: I work with freepastry api if you know it, so I can do a small scale local network, or a large scale (internet) ...

Answer (score 3):

As a commenter noted, you might just use DNS. If you are not able to obtain a DNS-entry for whatever reasons, or the server and the clients will run on the same network, you might consider using some kind of mDNS, with wich you wont need a  DNS-Server with your record up and running. Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDNS#Multicast_DNS for a introductionary overview

Answer (score 0):

Use a third-party broker server, that both the client and server knows about in advance.

Just set up a server anywhere with a known IP address. (Using a cloud server is a cheap and quick option.)

When the server starts, it sends its IP address to the broker server, and when the client starts, it querys the broker server for a server to connect to.

Of course you have to write a protocol for this, but it can be extremely simple.

Comment: judging from the post, I think the big problem for the poster is just to answer a homework question, not to think to deeply about security.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must remember how big the network you want to search?
and if it will be a bit problem for you then you can use the DNS its really useful.....

Comment: I work with freepastry api if you know it, so I can do a small scale local network, or a large scale (internet) ...

Answer (score 0):

If your server and client will run on your local network, use this beautiful MAC address : FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF ... ;) But DNS will be the best to use if the name stay the same.

Comment: I would say that when the server starts running can i change the hostname  to serv, can i do this in the server code (in C)?Because ,I do not know in advance which machine will run the server...

Comment: Do like a DHCP server does... when a client is new on the network, he ask where the DHCP server is (what IP) and the server negociate. Just do the same thing on both : server / client.